# Pandas: How to convert local time to UTC?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a pandas dataframe where I have a column consisting of strings of date times, these I have converted to datetime with pd.to_datetime(). Then I have tried to convert this column to UTC from Swedish Local time, but get an `NonExistentTimeError` when converting with pandas. How do I resolve this without removing timestamps?

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_dataframe(df['Time'])
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Stockholm')
```

My dataframe looks like this:

| Time | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-26 23:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-03-27 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2022-03-27 01:00:00 | 6 |
| 2022-03-27 02:00:00 | 8 |
| 2022-03-27 03:00:00 | 4 |
| 2022-03-27 04:00:00 | 11 |
| 2022-03-27 05:00:00 | 10 |

Comment: Could you please put an expected output to clarify the question?

Answer (score 0):

As the error

> NonExistentTimeError: 2022-03-27 02:00:00

tells you, that time did not exist in Stockholm local time. Due to the DST change, the hour after 1 am was 3 am, not 2 am. So to me, this looks like something wrong is happening during generation of this data, maybe worth investigating.

Anyways, what you can do is set `nonexistent` keyword, e.g. like

```py
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Stockholm', nonexistent='NaT')

df['Time']
0   2022-03-26 23:00:00+01:00
1   2022-03-27 00:00:00+01:00
2   2022-03-27 01:00:00+01:00
3                         NaT
4   2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00
5   2022-03-27 04:00:00+02:00
6   2022-03-27 05:00:00+02:00
Name: Time, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Stockholm]
```

see [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html) for different options.