# How to convert & localize naive datetimes (using daylight saving time) to aware datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have a dataframe including columns `Date` & `Time`, which are local clock readings (as strings). and the column `dst`, which indicates whether Daylight Saving Time is active or not using `W` for winter and `S`for summer.

I know the timezone is `Europe/Berlin`, resulting in a 1 hour shift from UTC during wintertime and a 2 hour shift during summertime.

I am very unhappy with this representation and want to convert to aware datetime objects in UTC and only give human readable times when needed.

```py
      Date      Time  dst
27.03.2022  01:15:00    W
27.03.2022  01:30:00    W
27.03.2022  01:45:00    W
27.03.2022  03:00:00    S
27.03.2022  03:15:00    S
27.03.2022  03:30:00    S
27.03.2022  03:45:00    S
27.03.2022  04:00:00    S
27.03.2022  04:15:00    S
27.03.2022  04:30:00    S
27.03.2022  04:45:00    S
27.03.2022  05:00:00    S
27.03.2022  05:15:00    S
```

**My first approach** was, retrieving a datetime object using pandas, localize it and subtracting two or one hours depending on the given dst, using numpy.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from dateutil import tz

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + df['Time'], format='%d.%m.%Y%H:%M:%S')
df['datetime_aware'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_localize(tz='Europe/Berlin')
df['datetime_aware_subtracted'] = np.where(df['dst']=='S', df['datetime_aware']-timedelta(hours=2),
                                           df['datetime_aware']-timedelta(hours=1))
```

This yields almost correct results, except between 03:00 - 05:00 (in `datetime`) the `datetime_aware_subtracted` column yields wrong result. One hour too much subtracted + one hour timeshift too little. I feel like substracting time over the dst boundary is not a good idea.

```py
        datetime               datetime_aware   datetime_aware_subtracted
27.03.2022 01:15    2022-03-27 01:15:00+01:00   2022-03-27 00:15:00+01:00
27.03.2022 01:30    2022-03-27 01:30:00+01:00   2022-03-27 00:30:00+01:00
27.03.2022 01:45    2022-03-27 01:45:00+01:00   2022-03-27 00:45:00+01:00
27.03.2022 03:00    2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00   2022-03-27 00:00:00+01:00
27.03.2022 03:15    2022-03-27 03:15:00+02:00   2022-03-27 00:15:00+01:00
27.03.2022 03:30    2022-03-27 03:30:00+02:00   2022-03-27 00:30:00+01:00
27.03.2022 03:45    2022-03-27 03:45:00+02:00   2022-03-27 00:45:00+01:00
27.03.2022 04:00    2022-03-27 04:00:00+02:00   2022-03-27 01:00:00+01:00
27.03.2022 04:15    2022-03-27 04:15:00+02:00   2022-03-27 01:15:00+01:00
27.03.2022 04:30    2022-03-27 04:30:00+02:00   2022-03-27 01:30:00+01:00
27.03.2022 04:45    2022-03-27 04:45:00+02:00   2022-03-27 01:45:00+01:00
27.03.2022 05:00    2022-03-27 05:00:00+02:00   2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00
27.03.2022 05:15    2022-03-27 05:15:00+02:00   2022-03-27 03:15:00+02:00
```

**My second approach**, was to inverse subtraction and localizing.

```py
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + df['Time'], format='%d.%m.%Y%H:%M:%S')
df['datetime_subtracted'] = np.where(df['dst']=='S', df['datetime']-timedelta(hours=2),
                                     df['datetime']-timedelta(hours=1))
df['datetime_subtracted_aware'] = df['datetime_subtracted'].dt.tz_localize(tz='Europe/Berlin')
```

This gives the correct naive results but after subtracting gives an `NonExistentTimeError` when localizing (rightfully so).

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 94, in f
    return self._delegate_method(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\accessors.py", line 123, in _delegate_method
    result = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 273, in tz_localize
    arr = self._data.tz_localize(tz, ambiguous, nonexistent)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\_mixins.py", line 84, in method
    return meth(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 1043, in tz_localize
    new_dates = tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc(
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\tzconversion.pyx", line 328, in pandas._libs.tslibs.tzconversion.tz_localize_to_utc
pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 2022-03-27 02:00:00
```

What are my best options to aware UTC datetime objects in `Europe/Berlin` timezone? In other words, create a new column `datetime_aware_localized` that shows the same date&time as the `datetime` column but is an aware datetime object in correct timezone.

Comment: Do not ever manually add or subtract hours from a time based on anything you think you know about the timezone. Always get a timezone library to do it for you. https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca

Comment: I'd appreciate a demonstration which timezone library handles this case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to clarify, localization works perfectly fine like

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + df['Time'], format='%d.%m.%Y%H:%M:%S').dt.tz_localize("Europe/Berlin")

0    2022-03-27 01:15:00+01:00
1    2022-03-27 01:30:00+01:00
2    2022-03-27 01:45:00+01:00
3    2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00
4    2022-03-27 03:15:00+02:00
5    2022-03-27 03:30:00+02:00
6    2022-03-27 03:45:00+02:00
7    2022-03-27 04:00:00+02:00
8    2022-03-27 04:15:00+02:00
9    2022-03-27 04:30:00+02:00
10   2022-03-27 04:45:00+02:00
11   2022-03-27 05:00:00+02:00
12   2022-03-27 05:15:00+02:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

If you need UTC, use

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + df['Time'], format='%d.%m.%Y%H:%M:%S').dt.tz_localize("Europe/Berlin").dt.tz_convert("UTC")

0    2022-03-27 00:15:00+00:00
1    2022-03-27 00:30:00+00:00
2    2022-03-27 00:45:00+00:00
3    2022-03-27 01:00:00+00:00
4    2022-03-27 01:15:00+00:00
5    2022-03-27 01:30:00+00:00
6    2022-03-27 01:45:00+00:00
7    2022-03-27 02:00:00+00:00
8    2022-03-27 02:15:00+00:00
9    2022-03-27 02:30:00+00:00
10   2022-03-27 02:45:00+00:00
11   2022-03-27 03:00:00+00:00
12   2022-03-27 03:15:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

---

regarding `NonExistentTimeError` error, you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73798180/10197418), where this is actually a problem and keyword `nonexistent` is necessary.

Comment: Maybe i'm on the wrong line of thought but how is that 3 hour gap correct?
`2    2022-03-27 01:45:00+01:00 equals 02:45:00 should be 00:45:00+01:00` and
`3    2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00 equals 05:00:00 should be 01:00:00+02:00`

Comment: @Magnus it's a [DST change](https://www.timeanddate.de/stadt/zeitumstellung/deutschland/berlin) (please also have a look at the other question I linked). Clocks changed from 1 am to 3 am on that date: the change from winter time (UTC+1) to summer time (UTC+2), i.e. a "jump ahead" by one hour. If you look at UTC, you see that there is no gap in the "time zone agnostic" time.

Comment: Familiar with DST, less familiar with reading timestamps correctly. I was adding the offset to get the actual date. Whereas the with UTC & timestamps it works the other way round. `03:15:00+02:00` means it's 03:15:00 and in a timezone that is 2 hours east from UTC. 
Marking solved, thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell [`tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) how to handle non-existing times:

> nonexistentstr, default ‘raise’
>
> A nonexistent time does not exist in a particular timezone where clocks moved forward due to DST. Valid values are:
>
> ‘shift_forward’ will shift the nonexistent time forward to the closest existing time
>
> ‘shift_backward’ will shift the nonexistent time backward to the closest existing time
>
> ‘NaT’ will return NaT where there are nonexistent times
>
> timedelta objects will shift nonexistent times by the timedelta
>
> ‘raise’ will raise an NonExistentTimeError if there are nonexistent times.

Replacing with NaT:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['Time'])
corr = pd.to_timedelta(df['dst'].map({'W': 1, 'S': 2}), unit='H')

# converting to NaT
dt.sub(corr).dt.tz_localize(tz='Europe/Berlin', nonexistent='NaT')
```

output:

```
0    2022-03-27 00:15:00+01:00
1    2022-03-27 00:30:00+01:00
2    2022-03-27 00:45:00+01:00
3    2022-03-27 01:00:00+01:00
4    2022-03-27 01:15:00+01:00
5    2022-03-27 01:30:00+01:00
6    2022-03-27 01:45:00+01:00
7                          NaT
8                          NaT
9                          NaT
10                         NaT
11   2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00
12   2022-03-27 03:15:00+02:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

shifting forward:

```
dt.sub(corr).dt.tz_localize(tz='Europe/Berlin', nonexistent='shift_forward')

0    2022-03-27 00:15:00+01:00
1    2022-03-27 00:30:00+01:00
2    2022-03-27 00:45:00+01:00
3    2022-03-27 01:00:00+01:00
4    2022-03-27 01:15:00+01:00
5    2022-03-27 01:30:00+01:00
6    2022-03-27 01:45:00+01:00
7    2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00
8    2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00
9    2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00
10   2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00
11   2022-03-27 03:00:00+02:00
12   2022-03-27 03:15:00+02:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

Comment: I don't think you should be subtracting DST hours, the comment by @Beetle - only localize to correct time zone.

Comment: @FObersteiner that's certainly a wise comment. That said, it can happen that a dataset contains incorrect data. The first part of my answer is just a different syntax for what OP was already doing, I answered to show the `nonexistent` part ;)

Comment: I'm all in the camp of not reinventing time related libraries and subsequently falling into one of the many pitfalls. That being said, the input data notation of the might make this step necessary.

In this case however, the results should look like the dates & times in the `datetime` column. So this solution does not work.

Comment: @Magnus so you want to purposely generate invalid datetime?

Comment: Something like `dt.sub(corr).astype(str)+'+'+df['dst'].map({'W': 1, 'S': 2}).astype(str).str.zfill(2)+':00'`, but it's quite wrong to do this IMO…

Comment: was reading timestamps incorrectly. marked @FObersteiner answer as correct.